# Giving Name (Heading) to Objects in JsonArray

Tags: java, json

I want to send following data to server. It contains JsonArray of JsonObjects as shown below.

```
{
    "users":[
        {"user-1":{
            "Name":"Amit",
            "Age":"32",
            "Gender":"male",
            "Hobby":"Cricket"
        }
        "user-2":{
            "Name":"Subodh",
            "Age":"30",
            "Gender":"male",
            "Hobby":"Chess"
        }
        "user-3":{
            "Name":"Mala",
            "Age":"27",
            "Gender":"female",
            "Hobby":"Singing"
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

This is how I wrote json code for the same.

```
    JSONObject userObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray userArray = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject user1 = new JSONObject();
    try {
        user1.put("Name", "Amit");
        user1.put("Age", "32");
        user1.put("Gender", "Male");
        user1.put("Hobby", "Cricket");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JSONObject user2 = new JSONObject();
    try {
        user2.put("Name", "Subodh");
        user2.put("Age", "30");
        user2.put("Gender", "Male");
        user2.put("Hobby", "Chess");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JSONObject user3 = new JSONObject();
    try {
        user3.put("Name", "Mala");
        user3.put("Age", "27");
        user3.put("Gender", "Female");
        user3.put("Hobby", "Singing");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    userArray.put(user1);
    userArray.put(user2);
    userArray.put(user3);
    try {
        userObject.put("user", userArray);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However I am not able to figure out how to give name to Objects (user-1, user-2 etc.) in the JsonArray. Can someone help to do that. I want to give Heading to each JsonObject in the JsonArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid.

Elements in *JSON arrays* don't have keys ("headings", as you call them). Only values in *JSON objects* have keys.

So, this is wrong:

```
{
    "users": [
        "user-1": {
            "Name": "Amit",
            "Age": "32",
            "Gender": "male",
            "Hobby": "Cricket"
        }
    ]
}
```

While this is correct:

```
{
    "users": {
        "user-1": {
            "Name": "Amit",
            "Age": "32",
            "Gender": "male",
            "Hobby": "Cricket"
        }
    }
 }
```

To get the correct JSON, simply use a `JSONObject` instead of a `JSONArray`:

```
JSONObject resultObject = new JSONObject();
JSONObject usersObject = new JSONObject();

JSONObject user1 = new JSONObject();
user1.put("Name", "Amit");
user1.put("Age", "32");
user1.put("Gender", "Male");
user1.put("Hobby", "Cricket");

usersObject.put("user-1", user1);

// repeat for user 2, 3, 4, ...

resultObject.put("users", usersObject);
```

Comment: Ohh.. I got it. Had done mistake with JsonArray. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score -4):

Write the JSON object name like below code in every JSONObject creation :-

```
 JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject("user1 ");
 try {
 jsonobj.put("Name", "Amit");
 jsonobj.put("Age", "32");
 jsonobj.put("Gender", "Male");
 jsonobj.put("Hobby", "Cricket");
  } catch (JSONException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();  
  }
```